# Compiling own QtCreator Plugin fails

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator

I'm trying to create my own QtCreator Plugin by following [this](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-extending/first-plugin.html) guide.

So I cloned [this](https://git.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator.git) repo and checked the v2.8.1 tagged commit out (c3ed746c).

Then I copied my QtCreator 2.8.1 directory and created a new Qt Creator Plugin project.

Then I create a new file in my project directory called MyPlugin.json.

If I try to compile my plug in I get this error:

> e:\qtprojects\build-myplugin-desktop_qt_5_1_1_msvc2012_32bit-debug\debug../../MyPlugin/mypluginplugin.h(6) : fatal error C1083:  Cannot open include file: "extensionsystem/iplugin.h": No such file or directory
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-MyPlugin-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_mypluginplugin.obj] Error 2
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-MyPlugin-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
>   10:56:51: The process "E:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project myplugin (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 32bit)
>   When executing step 'Make'
>   10:56:51: Elapsed time: 00:01.

What do I have to do to make it work?

This are the source files:

#### myplugin.pro

```
DEFINES += MYPLUGIN_LIBRARY

 # MyPlugin files

SOURCES += mypluginplugin.cpp

HEADERS += mypluginplugin.h \
        myplugin_global.h \
        mypluginconstants.h

 # Qt Creator linking

 ## set the QTC_SOURCE environment variable to override the setting here
QTCREATOR_SOURCES = $$(QTC_SOURCE)
isEmpty(QTCREATOR_SOURCES):QTCREATOR_SOURCES=E:/QtProjects/_QtCreatorPlugIns/qt-creator

 ## set the QTC_BUILD environment variable to override the setting here
IDE_BUILD_TREE = $$(QTC_BUILD)
isEmpty(IDE_BUILD_TREE):IDE_BUILD_TREE=E:/QtProjects/_QtCreatorPlugIns/QtCreator

 ## uncomment to build plugin into user config directory
 ## <localappdata>/plugins/<ideversion>
 ##    where <localappdata> is e.g.
 ##    "%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtProject\qtcreator" on Windows Vista and later
 ##    "$XDG_DATA_HOME/data/QtProject/qtcreator" or "~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator" on Linux
 ##    "~/Library/Application Support/QtProject/Qt Creator" on Mac
 # USE_USER_DESTDIR = yes

PROVIDER = MyCompany

include($$QTCREATOR_SOURCES/src/qtcreatorplugin.pri)
```

#### myplugin_global.h

```
#ifndef MYPLUGIN_GLOBAL_H
#define MYPLUGIN_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtGlobal>

#if defined(MYPLUGIN_LIBRARY)
#  define MYPLUGINSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYPLUGINSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MYPLUGIN_GLOBAL_H
```

#### mypluginconstants.h

```
#ifndef MYPLUGINCONSTANTS_H
#define MYPLUGINCONSTANTS_H

namespace MyPlugin {
    namespace Constants {

        const char ACTION_ID[] = "MyPlugin.Action";
        const char MENU_ID[] = "MyPlugin.Menu";

    } // namespace MyPlugin
} // namespace Constants

#endif // MYPLUGINCONSTANTS_H
```

#### mypluginplugin.h

```
#ifndef MYPLUGIN_H
#define MYPLUGIN_H

#include "myplugin_global.h"

#include <extensionsystem/iplugin.h>

namespace MyPlugin {
    namespace Internal {

        class MyPluginPlugin : public ExtensionSystem::IPlugin
        {
                Q_OBJECT
                Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QtCreatorPlugin" FILE "MyPlugin.json")

            public:
                MyPluginPlugin();
                ~MyPluginPlugin();

                bool initialize(const QStringList &arguments, QString *errorString);
                void extensionsInitialized();
                ShutdownFlag aboutToShutdown();

            private slots:
                void triggerAction();
        };

    } // namespace Internal
} // namespace MyPlugin

#endif // MYPLUGIN_H
```

#### mypluginplugin.cpp

```
#include "mypluginplugin.h"
#include "mypluginconstants.h"

#include <coreplugin/icore.h>
#include <coreplugin/icontext.h>
#include <coreplugin/actionmanager/actionmanager.h>
#include <coreplugin/actionmanager/command.h>
#include <coreplugin/actionmanager/actioncontainer.h>
#include <coreplugin/coreconstants.h>

#include <QAction>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>

#include <QtPlugin>

using namespace MyPlugin::Internal;

MyPluginPlugin::MyPluginPlugin()
{
    // Create your members
}

MyPluginPlugin::~MyPluginPlugin()
{
    // Unregister objects from the plugin manager's object pool
    // Delete members
}

bool MyPluginPlugin::initialize(const QStringList &arguments, QString *errorString)
{
    // Register objects in the plugin manager's object pool
    // Load settings
    // Add actions to menus
    // Connect to other plugins' signals
    // In the initialize method, a plugin can be sure that the plugins it
    // depends on have initialized their members.

    Q_UNUSED(arguments)
    Q_UNUSED(errorString)

    QAction *action = new QAction(tr("MyPlugin action"), this);
    Core::Command *cmd = Core::ActionManager::registerAction(action, Constants::ACTION_ID,
                                                             Core::Context(Core::Constants::C_GLOBAL));
    cmd->setDefaultKeySequence(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+Alt+Meta+A")));
    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(triggerAction()));

    Core::ActionContainer *menu = Core::ActionManager::createMenu(Constants::MENU_ID);
    menu->menu()->setTitle(tr("MyPlugin"));
    menu->addAction(cmd);
    Core::ActionManager::actionContainer(Core::Constants::M_TOOLS)->addMenu(menu);

    return true;
}

void MyPluginPlugin::extensionsInitialized()
{
    // Retrieve objects from the plugin manager's object pool
    // In the extensionsInitialized method, a plugin can be sure that all
    // plugins that depend on it are completely initialized.
}

ExtensionSystem::IPlugin::ShutdownFlag MyPluginPlugin::aboutToShutdown()
{
    // Save settings
    // Disconnect from signals that are not needed during shutdown
    // Hide UI (if you add UI that is not in the main window directly)
    return SynchronousShutdown;
}

void MyPluginPlugin::triggerAction()
{
    QMessageBox::information(Core::ICore::mainWindow(),
                             tr("Action triggered"),
                             tr("This is an action from MyPlugin."));
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(MyPlugin, MyPluginPlugin)
```

Directories

```
E:\QtProjects\_QtCreatorPlugIns> tree

├───qt-creator
│   ├───bin
│   ├───dist
│   ├───doc
│   ├───lib
│   ├───qbs
│   ├───scripts
│   ├───share
│   ├───srcn64interrupt
│   └───testsster
├───QtCreator
│   ├───bin
│   ├───lib0
│   └───share
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're a linux user, you can download `qtcreator-dev`. But, i don't know how it works on Windows.

1. Open terminal
2. Type : `sudo apt-get install qtcreator-dev`
3. Done.

Comment: +1 nice and easy... but how to do on other distros? (Debian has no package qtcreator-dev. Do I need to add some apt-repositories?)

Comment: If your distro still use `apt`. Then it's fine. 
You can manually add PPA of Ubuntu SDK Team (`ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`) by reading the following guide, http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-add-launchpad-ppas-in-debian-via.html.

If not, I doubt, I can't provide the answer.
Cheers.

Comment: The `dev` version imho is just Qt Creator build in debug mode. So if (like me) someone is compiling Qt Creator from source, he/she should also do a Debug alongside the Release version of the IDE.